# How do I create a radial css3 border gradient shadow

Tags: css, border-shadow

I have two columns that can stretch to variable heights, the designer wants to have a shadow between the two columns, but as you can see the image fades out at the top and the bottom. That means I can't just use a background image using css that is left aligned in the column on the right.

[image: Columns with a radial shadow in between]

So then I though maybe I can use a css 3 border shadow that has a radial gradient. I am probably going to use table cells to do this because I need the shadow to stretch to the height of the tallest column. How do I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Previous answers doesn't really answer your question: *"How do I create a radial css3 border gradient shadow"*

You can use a radial gradient to simulate a border shadow without images.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sonic1980/wRuaZ/

[image]

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 0%, 50% 5px, #aaa 0%, white 100%);
                                    |       |        |        |
                                    |       |        |        +--> color end     
                                    |       |        +--> color start
                                    |       +--> size of gradient ellipse (x-axis, y-axis)
                                    +---> position of ellipse center
```

It's easy to modify to make it vertical or implement using :before or :after pseudo-classes.

Another example, an `<hr>` tag with shadow: http://jsfiddle.net/sonic1980/65Hfc/

Comment: Nice answer, Peter, but it's fairly intense on the browser requirements :)

Comment: Replace the `-webkit-`… line with `radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 50% 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%)` to make it work in a standard and cross-browser way.

Answer (score 0):

i have a suggestion that you do not need use css3, you may use two different class, one is normal, and other has background. And when loading page finish, and call js method, settimeout to dely some seconds, toggle class.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am just going to use the image, and set a min-height on the div :-)

```
.column.right {
  padding-left: 30px;
  background: url(/img/shadow.png) no-repeat left top;
  min-height: 265px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would actually allow for a dynamic height column, but it only has IE8+ support.

What you'd do is apply a `background-image` positioned to the edge of the tallest column. Then you could use the `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements, set to `absolute` positioning of `top:0;` and `bottom:0` respectively, to set the 'cap' on the shadows.

Does that make sense? Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3rFz/) that shows it using a border and text, instead of images.

Of course, the `height` parameter of the `div` in the JSFiddle is of no consequence; it could be `min-height` or nonexistent. I just set it to give the `div` some size.

Comment: So would the after and before act like masks and have the tapered off shadows using background-image in them? Thats pretty cool :) You could also just add extra divs and be less semantic and still use absolute positioning

Comment: Yeah you've got the idea. Using more `div`s makes it lose its semantic power, but does give it deeper `IE` support, which might just be worth it!